# How do I set up Minecraft Cross Play in Same House / Same Wifi?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-legacy-console, nintendo-switch

I have been trying to set up Minecraft so that my kids can play it on our home wifi across multiple devices. I am so confused.. too many versions of Minecraft

I own:

- Minecraft Java Edition (Windows 10)
- Minecraft: Xbox Edition
- Minecraft for Windows 10 (through the Windows Store)
- I also have a Nintendo Switch

with this combination of computers/Xbox/Nintendo Switch can someone tell me step by step how to get 2 or 3 players in my house playing in the same Minecraft World (without spending any more money?)

thanks.. yes I have googled this to death. I have also watched many many unhelpful youtube videos.. and I am a minecraft noobie.. thanks

Comment: I can already tell you that Java edition does not play with the others, at least not using official software. There are some fan-made projects that bridge it, but they are fundamentally different games.

Comment: There's the original platform-specific "Minecraft: X Edition" versions, and then a newer "Minecraft for X" (commonly called "Minecraft Bedrock"), which is the unified version that supports cross-play. Generally having an "edition" will get you the newer version for free. I don't really use Minecraft Bedrock so not sure specifically how to set up LAN on it, but using all Bedrock (no "edition"s) would be where you'd need to start.

Answer (score 5):

On Win10 there exist two versions: Bedrock/Win10 edition (just called Minecraft nowadays), and Java. On XboxOne there are two versions: Console edition (deprecated, can no longer buy), and Bedrock edition (and bedrock is a free download if you had console). On Nintendo Switch there are two versions, console edition and bedrock (and bedrock is a free download if you had console).

If you want to play multiplayer with another device, the general rule is the devices must have the same edition.

You have Bedrock on win10 (it's the one that comes from the Microsoft Windows store, not mojang.com). You don't say what you have on XBoxOne, but if it's not bedrock, then download bedrock for free. If you want the Switch to get in too, get Bedrock for it (the only version purchasable today). On each device (win10/xbox/switch), log in to a different XboxLive account. For each account, friend the other two accounts. Then on one device, start a world. On the other devices, that world should appear in the friends tab.

Android and iOS phones can also join, as they run Bedrock edition.

Answer (score 3):

Cross play is ONLY for bedrock (Win 10 ver. through the store, mobile, xBox, and switch) Usually you can set up a lan server by going to your world options, multiplayer, then there should be an option to broadcast to LAN. Another option is that you need to sign in to xBox live (on ALL devices you want to use) with different accounts. Friend each account together and in world options turn on multiplayer game, allow friends of friends.

To view steps, go to [this link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/w4bu9n8popqaani/Mc_bedrock_instructions_for_joining_each_other.pdf/file) (New link)

Comment: Or you could edit your existing post

Answer (score 2):

**Nintendo Switch Local Play with iPad**

What I setup. 2 iPads, and 2 Switch consoles. This isn't as straightforward as I thought it should be.

**A Switch Will Host the Game**

If a switch is going to host there are couple of things you might get hung up on (I did).

1. **DO NOT:** select "(Y) Connect to a Local Network". Yeah I know this what you think you should do. But don't do it. It won't work for cross-device play.
2. **Everyone Needs a Microsoft Account.**. Log into your MS accounts on every device.
3. Make sure you are all "friends" on Microsoft online.
4. **You Need a Switch Online Account!**  You need to be able to get online to play Minecraft cross-devices play. Switch -> iPad.
5. **Enable Multiplayer**. Make sure multiplayer is enabled. When you start the game the Switch will login to Nintendo Online and your Microsoft ID will be broadcasted.
6. Start up the other devices and join your game.

I was able to connect on iOS, and another Switch this way. Now there are some confusing issues here. For one I was able to login into the MS account without having a Switch Online account. I was also able to host the game and connect to another Switch device without a Switch Online account. However, my iPad could not see the local game. I welcome input if there is another way to do this. Hope this helps.

**As of iOS 13 you can use an PS4, or XBox controller on your iPad.** This makes the iPad a great Minecraft machine.

Comment: You shouldn't need an xbox live account for multiplayer on the same network?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a LAN (Local Area Network) or if that doesn't work, thanks to the Better Together Update, you can now do crossplay. On the Switch for example, when you press "Play", you just navigate over to the "Friends" tab by pressing 'R' (top right bumper), type in the person's username you want to add, and they will be added to the friends list. It will also show you when they are online as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

- your windows 10 device

  (Using minecraft for Windows 10)
- your Nintendo switch
- your Xbox

For this.

Unfortunately, you won’t be able to use java edition, as it doesn’t work in the same way as bedrock and you can’t cross play between the two.

### In steps:

1. Create or enter an existing world on one of the devices.
2. Go into minecraft on the other devices and press play. There should be a tab called friends.
3. Tap on friends. The world should show up as something like ‘LAN World’ with the world name and the name of the player on the device that created the world. This is probably set to ‘Steve’ unless anyone changed it (or signed in with an Xbox live account, but don’t worry about that.)

> • Be sure not to get confused with the ‘joinable friends’ option. This is completely separate. The world should NOT appear below joinable friends if it is a LAN world.

4. Tap on the world. You should now be in the world.

I would have sent screenshots, but I am afraid that I am unable to due to a problem with my PC. I hope you manage to get this to work. Good luck :)