# Can I play Minecraft Bedrock Edition locally on multiple devices via WiFi?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have Win 10, Android and Switch versions of the game, but only one Microsoft account. Is it possible to cross play in these versions via WiFi without making extra Microsoft accounts? I also checked this Thread:
[How do I set up Minecraft Cross Play in Same House / Same Wifi?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336675/how-do-i-set-up-minecraft-cross-play-in-same-house-same-wifi)

but the answer didn't really help.

Comment: Yes it is possible.